# JSchException while connecting through SFTP

Tags: java, sftp

I am getting the following exception when I try to connect it for the first time. This exception occurs only on the first time, when i loop the same for the second time, am not getting the exception and connection succeeds. Can anyone help me on this?

```
SftpConnect::init Exception: 
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: connection is closed by foreign host
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: connection is closed by foreign host
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:240)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:154)
at com.alcatel.muse.common.sftp.SftpConnect.init(Unknown Source)
at com.alcatel.muse.common.sftp.SftpConnect.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please add your code which you are using for the connect.

Comment: If you can, also add logs from the server side.

Comment: this answer maybe can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147240/jschexception-connection-is-closed-by-foreign-host