# JSchException: connection is closed by foreign host

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, sap-cloud-platform

Am trying to pull files from an SFTP server using JSCH. I am getting the files without any problem from local host, but from the cloud server(SAP Cloud Platform), its giving this Connection Is Closed By Foreign Host exception from JSCH. I am getting the system proxy and port and setting the proxy with the request. 
Had seen the question asked several times, but none of them is solving my problem. The code snippet :

```
String SFTPHOST = "hostname";
int    SFTPPORT = 22;
String SFTPUSER = "username";
String SFTPPASS = "password";
String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "directory";

Session     session     = null;
Channel     channel     = null;
ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

try{
    String proxyHost = System.getProperty("https.proxyHost");
    String proxyPort = System.getProperty("https.proxyPort");

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);
    session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);

    if(proxyHost != null && proxyPort != null) {
        ProxyHTTP  proxy = new ProxyHTTP(proxyHost, Integer.parseInt(proxyPort));
        session.setProxy(proxy);
    }
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
    channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
    Vector filelist = channelSftp.ls(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
    for(int i=0; i<filelist.size();i++){
        LsEntry entry = (LsEntry) filelist.get(i);
        response.getWriter().append(entry.getFilename());
    }

}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem, at least not in its current form. The remote ssh server is deciding to drop your ssh connection. You need to troubleshoot that on the ssh server.

Comment: Can you download the files using any standalone SFTP client?